Is there a way I can test polars locally using Azurite?
Azurite provides a local URI - 'http://127.0.0.1/devstoreaccount/{container_name}' to point to a file, but polars doesn't seem to have a way to interact with them. I tried using various 'storage_options' parameters but couldn't actually get it working.
I've tried -

Using Localhost url provided by Azurite and plugging it in in polars.
I've tried doing (1) with storage options - 'azure_storage_use_emulator'
I've tried finding out the local directory where azurite creates any folders (using --hns --loose params) and seeing whether I can directly use absolute paths with polars.

Nothing worked
